Are there any Examples of Offset curve based AMM in the wild
The offset curve can be seen as a combination of the constant price and constant product curve. It follows the constant product curve dynamics, but allows for the pool creator to set an "offset" on one side. The invariant for the curve is:
(A_total) * (B_total + B_offset) = invariant
This is useful for initial token offerings, where the token creator wants to sell some new token as a swap without putting up the capital to fund the other side of the swap. This is similar to the constant price curve, but the key difference is that the offset curve captures normal market dynamics, in that the offered token price will increase as it is bought.
https://spl.solana.com/token-swap
I was trying to see if anyone has actually implemented this before, could not find any live examples.

As its author, I can proudly say that I don't think anyone's using it :-D

:) i wonder why? Wouldnt it also serve the purpose of a bonding curve to bootstrap liquidity and then also serve as the AMM. For eg: pump fun uses a bonding curve and then moves the LP to raydium, wouldnt this be a better arch?

That was the whole idea, and would be the perfect use case, but maybe people are scared about the lack of real liquidity supporting the token price

I am interested in taking this to the market, happy to give you credit/clip. Hit me up at @maxbox83 if interested

Haha don't worry about it, I'll just be happy if you use it
